# How can I output the custom fields wrapping with HTML

Tags: custom-field, customization, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to publish custom fields created using the plugin "Advanced Custom fields". I am able to display them on posts and custom post types as raw output. But I want to wrap html around the output.

Ex: Field-1(field name is 'the_one'): I want to publish any content like Text or Date with the format I want.

```
<?php if( get_field('the_one') != '' ) : ?>
        <span class=the_one field1"><a href="<?php echo get_field('the_one'); ?>"><?php _e( '<b data-icon="info" class="inner-content">Content</b>', $post_id ); ?></a></span>
```

Field-2 (field name is 'the_link'): I want the URLs for website urls be published converting to links

```
<?php if( get_field('the_link') != '' ) : ?>
    <span class=the_link field2"><a href="<?php echo get_field('the_one'); ?>"><?php _e( '<b data-icon="web" class="inner-content">Special Category</b>', $post_id ); ?></a></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Could any one help me with this?

Thanks!

Update: I have no success creating custom fields by own. So tried to use ACF again. Here is the loop.php code- http://pastebin.com/7UE2izdg. Custom fields are in the lines 58 and 59.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things in your code, I don't know why you implemented like that. In my view the corrected code should be:

```
<?php
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'the_link', true ) != '' ) : ?>
    <span class="the_one field1">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'the_link', true )); ?>">
            <b data-icon="info" class="inner-content"><?php echo _e( 'Content', 'theme-text-domain' ); ?></b>
        </a>
    </span>
<?php
endif;
```

Rather than any ACF command, I'd like to go with WordPress default code [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), and it's a fine one. I found some syntax error, where you started a span class without a double quote. `_e()` is a [translation parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology) that demands a theme text domain, NOT a post_id.

```
<?php _e( 'my text', 'text-domain' ); ?>
```

It's just a simple string thing. So you can leave it there and can embrace it with any kind of HTML outside the PHP.

And another conceptual thing is:
ACF is just a nice plugin to let the user do nice things with Custom Fields. But in core Custom Fields are all same, whether by plugin or core codes. They are the **Post Meta**. So whether checking they exists or not, or echoing them is always same as WordPress do, and it's the `get_post_meta()`.

Comment: Few things. Don't put variable if you don't use it (`$single=true` in `get_post_meta` calls). Also you should escape attributes... User can input anything in meta field and it would be good to be sure, that it won't break the page...

Comment: Thanks @KrzysiekDróżdż. I'll keep in mind in next move. :)

Comment: Hello @MayeenulIslam, I tried to use the code given and I got an issue. The page content is broken and I can't see the post content(showing everything blank). I think I done something wrong on my end as I never created custom fields myself by scratch. 

I have updated the original post with the copy of loop.php and ACF's fields I created. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Please confirm that without my code, your page is working properly, except the custom field thing - is that right?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Yes! You are right. Without the code, the page appears fine.